# php: How to get element in array by index using variable-variables

Tags: php, variable-variables

If I have:

```
<?php
$params=[
    [
        'string'
    ]
];
//params get from $this->params()->fromPost();
$abc='params[0][0]';//$abc dynamiccly
```

I cannot access `$params[0]`

How to get `string` element?

I try to use

```
echo $$abc;
```

But

> Notice: Undefined variable params[0][]

Comment: Your $params is not an array. Use array syntax to use $params[0] property

Comment: @SunilPachlangia this syntax is correct since PHP 5.4.

Comment: Remove single quotes and add $ sign in $abc='params[0]';

Comment: I was edited question just now. But $abc is dynamically. So I cannot use this way. Anyway, thank @SunilPachlangia.

Comment: Basically you can't do that directly as you're trying. You have two options. First is to parse `$abc` string to get separately variable name and index value (e.g. as roberto06 showed in his answer), but that's not efficient to do so much work only to get variable's value. I would suggest (if possible) to change your data flow design which is in this case the incoming value from POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$abc` is defined dynamically, you have to split it in two variables : `$arrayName` and `$arrayKey`, as such :

```
$params = array('string');
$abc = 'params[0]';
$arrayName = substr($abc,0,strpos($abc,'['));
$arrayIndex = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '',$abc);
echo ${$arrayName}[$arrayIndex]; // returns "string"
```

Comment: You have defined the variable dynamically, you can access the value using loop -

Answer (score 2):

use below way to access string

```
$params=[
    'string'
];
$abc='params';

$new = $$abc;
echo $new[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the values of dynamic varible you can execute a loop-

```
<?php
$params=[
    'string'
];
$abc= 'params';

foreach($$abc as $k=>$v){
    echo $v;
}

?>
```

If you want to access it directly by index so you need to reassign the dynamic variable in another variable like `$newArr = $$abc` and then access $newArr.